# Use php simpleXML to sort some nodes in a soap request? XSLT?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, soap

How can I apply XLST to a SOAP request using PHP simpleXML and XLST? This seems absent in the docs as far as simpleXML's implimentation of the XSLT processor. It has XPATH, but that can't really address my issue of sorting nodes after I get the request...

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not SimpleXML:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load("*.xml");
$xsltproc = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltproc->importStylesheet("*.xsl");
$resultdoc = $xsltproc->transformToDoc($xmldoc);
```

Comment: does that work on xml that's not in a file? for instance,  soap client return results as an object